# Spring cloud gateway add header from authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

A client hit a route on my spring cloud gateway 2 with its certificate.
I succesfully authenticate client with an x509 authentication, then, before forwarding the request to the downstream service i'd like to add the principal name to a cutom header of the the request.

I have created my filter, but i can't get the principal name into the header value.

Here is my gateway filter apply method implementation

```
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
 return new GatewayFilter() {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    Mono<String> clientName = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
      .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
      .map(Authentication::getName);
    
    String headerValue = getClientNameFromMono(clientName);
                
    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
      .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.add("X-Client-name", headerValue)).build();

    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
}
```

Problem is how to properly set headervalue, clientName.block() throws exception...
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I found that `TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory` does something very close to my needs.
Here is what i did:

```java
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
            .map(Principal::getName)
            .map(clientName -> withCustomHeader(exchange, clientName))
            .defaultIfEmpty(exchange).flatMap(chain::filter);
}

private ServerWebExchange withCustomHeader(ServerWebExchange exchange, String clientName) {
    return exchange.mutate()
            .request(r -> r.headers(headers -> headers.add("X-client-name", clientName)).build();
}
```

It works like a charm!!